# When or How should we pass the params to the URL?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, url

Using PHP, HTML and Javascript.
With PHP we are using a MVC Framework.

I have a fundamental question regarding web communication, that perhaps someone could clear some things here.

REST apart, and taking only "post" and "get":

Let's say that, if we do:
http://blabla.com/companyA/income/

It will list all income of a given company.

If we do:
http://blabla.com/companyA/income/2010/

It will list all income on 2010 for that company.

And so on.

Now, I wish to allow the user to, from a *html form*, select some values, and according to those values, return, from the server, the appropriate data.

How does this work?
a) Should we concatenate the URL string on the *client side*, (*form action*) and send it to the server side?

b) Our, should we send the params to the server side, and it returns the URL?

Anyway will work? Only one way will work? What are the consequences of those paths? Is there a third possibility?

Comment: This is a pretty wide/open ended question, at least I think it's hard to answer. I would research projects a) only serving generated HTML (such as a static blog generator, maybe Jekyll or something like it but written in php); b) serving templates generated on the server side, such as any php project using Twig, which usually is complemented with updated templates through ajax; c) SPA, from the link in my answer. Those are the most common paradigms to choose from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> a) Should we concatenate the URL string on the client side, (form action) and send it to the server side?

That's how it's always been done historically and it still works fine. It's the equivalent of constructing the complete HTML by hand, but using PHP (or any server side language) to help you remove manual labor, by basing the HTML on the data you have easy access to.

> b) Our, should we send the params to the server side, and it returns the URL?

That's unnecessary, you already have all the data ready so going with a) is more solid since it lets the client become a bit dumber, by excluding the render-url-from-arguments logic.

> Is there a third possibility?

Yes. Since you already expose lists of resources at /companyA/income/2010/ (perhaps through JSON), you could serve an empty page from the server side, trigger an ajax call to your backend and generating the list dynamically on the client side. This brings a bunch of things to think of, some are:

- How is SEO affected when (google) bots request empty pages?
- Can we reuse the rendering logic for different views, without reloading the empty page?

You could read up on SPA, or, [Single-page applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application).

Answer (score 0):

You should make url when processing with PHP, so you can pass ID or any other information from server. Making URL from client side requires additional processing.

```
<form action="companyA/income/<?php echo (int)$years; ?>">
    ...

<form action="<?php echo $this->makeUrl('companyA/income', $years); ?>">
    ...
```